# Spring bean scopes, possibility of configuring default scope

Tags: java, spring, scope

I was wondering if configuration for a default scope was possible on the event of a mentioned scope being not found, for instance consider the class :

```
@Component
@Scope("undefinedScope")
public myClass
```

This alone would result on a IllegalStateException, "No scope registered for "undefinedScope" error". If possible I would like to tell Spring to autowire classes as singleton, if the desired scope is not found. Any workarounds ?

Comment: create your custom scope http://javapapers.com/spring/custom-scope-for-spring-bean/ in your implementation if your scope is not defined then change it to singleton as name instead of your undefinedScope (Assuming you know what would be the string value of your scope tag that you are going to use)

Comment: Due to creating my custom scope, I'm facing this problem in the first place. This is not the answer I'm looking for.